# in VB trying to make a radio button dependent on another answer

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm trying to make a radio button list disabled or enabled depending on an answer from another radio button selection, this is the code that I have put together but have been unsuccessful getting it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // enable May we contact your present employer if Employed Now is yes

        function EmployedNowYes(answer) {

            if (answer == "Yes") {
                document.getElementById("<%=ContactEmployer.ClientID %>").enabled = true;
            }

            if (answer == "No") {
                document.getElementById("<%=ContactEmployer.ClientID %>").enabled = false;
            }

        }

    </script>
Are you employed now?
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="EmployedNow" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" onclick ="EmployedNowYes(this.value)">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="No" onclick ="EmployedNowYes(this.value)">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" ControlToValidate="EmployedNow"
                    ErrorMessage="* Required field." ForeColor="Red"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td><td class="style42" valign="top">
                May we contact your present employer:
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="ContactEmployer" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem >Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem >No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            </td>
```

Comment: Have you put an `alert()` in your `EmployedNowYes()` function to see if it was being called?

Comment: Why do not you use the server side `SelectedIndexChanged` Event to change `ContactEmployer.visible` property depending on the selection? Especially since you tagged this question also with vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in Javascript you need to write...

```
document.getElementById("<%=ContactEmployer.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("<%=ContactEmployer.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
```

You may also find that the values of disabled controls are not returned to the code-behind in the postback.